# getElementsByTagName 'undefined' in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xml-parsing, getelementsbytagname

I am having a problem with getElementsByTagName. I am trying to pull information from an xml file I received from the server using ajax. In IE it is works fine, but when I try to run it on Chrome or FireFox I get an "undefined".

**Javascript**:

```
function parseMessage()
{
    doc = request.responseXML;
    sum = "";

    for (var i=0; i< doc.getElementsByTagName('coupon').length; i=i+1)
    {
        var lat2 = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('latitude').item(i).text;
        var longi2 = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('longitude').item(i).text;
        var latlng  = new google.maps.LatLng( lat2 , longi2 ); 
        var product =  doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('productname').item(i).text;
        // marker[i] = createMarker(map2, product, latlng, description);

        sum = sum + description+ " "+ product + lat2 + longi2;                          
    }

    document.write(sum);
}
```

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<coupons>
-<coupon id="1">
<productname>Bigmac</productname>
<companyname>Macdonalds</companyname>
<latitude>32.015954</latitude>
<longitude>34.755228</longitude>
</coupon>
-<coupon id="2">
<productname>Crocs</productname>
<companyname>Crocs</companyname>
<latitude>32.079375</latitude>
<longitude>34.769325</longitude>
</coupon>
-<coupon id="3">
<productname>Nike Shoks</productname>
<companyname>NIKE</companyname>
<latitude>32.048825</latitude>
<longitude>34.785461</longitude>
</coupon>
-<coupon id="4">
.....
```

Comment: Given the posted XML, what are you trying to do? What is expected to happen from the use of `item(i)`?

Comment: I am trying to get the information of the xml document and to create a marker from this information on google map for every coupon element in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of elements; which can't be operated on as a group, so you'd have to select a *particular* node on which to work:

```
getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0]; // for the first element.
```

The second problem is that:

```
getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0].item(i);
```

Should be used to access a property, or attribute, of a particular element, and `item(i)` is *neither*, though it may be set/used somewhere that we're not seeing.

If you're trying to access one of the element's children (and in your posted code the `latitude` elements don't have any children), you could use:

```
getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0].childNodes[i];
```

And `text()` doesn't return, or do, anything in plain JavaScript. If you're using the jQuery  `text()` method, then that only works on jQuery objects, if you're trying to access the text content of the current nodes, then:

```
getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0].textContent; // for Firefox, Chrome...
```

Or:

```
getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0].innerText; // for IE
```

Comment: I guess that the examples of code i seen on the internet were not what i was needed: getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0].textContent; solved my problem for Chrome and FF but now i dont see my markers in IE. need to build a function that check on what browser i am and works acordingly.Thanks for the answer you helped me a lot.